# Python: Scraping inconsistency between local and server calls

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, server

I have been scraping data from my server for some time and everything was fine until a week ago. Since last week, the data I have been scraping comes back wrong. There is no error, the code executes fine but the data is simply wrong (the information is different from the website). The website I am scraping has not changed. I have changed nothing in my code.

So I ran the **exact same code** on my local computer and noticed that the data I scrape is right whereas I get it wrong from my server. I supposed it was related to my IP address, so I installed a VPN on my server and tried scraping (again with the same code) with the new IP address (through the VPN). The data I get is still wrong. I have also tried changing the header, that did not solve the issue. I do not understand how this is possible and what I can do to get right data again.

The operating system on my server is Debian Bullseye. My local OS is Windows 11.
The scraper is made in Python and is as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

header = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}

url = "https://somewebsite.ch"

#Get the information from the website
response = requests.get(url, headers=header)


#Transform it in a workable format
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, features='lxml')
```

Then I do some data manipulation and wrangling but there is no need to write down that part as the data returned into the variable soup is already not correct.

I would be very grateful if someone could tell me what to try to solve that issue.

I installed an VPN to change my IP and that did not work.
I changed the header in the scraping request but that did not help as well.

**EDIT**

In order to be more precise and get the appropriate help, here is the website I am trying to scrape.

https://www.homegate.ch/louer/biens-immobiliers/canton-vaud/liste-annonces?ep=1&o=dateCreated-desc

In order to see the discrepancies between the website and the scraping, anyone can send a GET request from Postman to this website. You will notice instantly that the prices are different from what is displayed on the website.

The goal obviously is to recover the good prices.

Many thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: This might not apply here, but I know of a website that tries to identify bots and feed them wrong information.

Comment: Any chance that could come from different Python environments on both sides?

Comment: @R_D, No that should not. I have recreated the same environment using conda and an yaml file. Just the packages OS-dependant are different. The rest is identical.